# How to set iPhone alarm programmatically?

Tags: iphone, calendar, notifications, custom-controls, alarm

This is a very straightforward question. I am developing an iphone app in which I am using a custom calendar. The user can set an alarm in this app. The events which the user adds to the calendar should not be visible in the default calendar application, which means I can't use default calendar application.

How do I set the alarm programmatically without replicating changes in default calendar?

**Edit**: I have used the iphonecal application by tinyfool for the calendar. If there is any way in that application to add timely alerts then please tell me. I couldn't find such functionality in that app.

Comment: @Rob:Thanks for editing.It's also important to use clean language while asking question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [local notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to set up alarms for a certain time.

Comment: Yes,I thought about that option,but I want to give support from iOS 3.2 and local notifications are available from iOS 4.0.

Comment: Multitasking isn't available in 3.2. There's no way to let a user quit an app and get a notification.

Comment: Yes,you are very much correct.So should I give support from iOS 4.0?Isn't there any way?I have edited the question for more clarification.

Comment: It's OK to drop 3.x support, iOS 4 has been out for a long time and it seems that the majority of users have moved to 4 by now.

Comment: Thanks nevan....I will definitely look into this.If anyone have more regarding this topic,please share it:)

Comment: I agree with nevan: there's no way to do this on OS3 (unless you set up a push notification server). If you want to play alarms when the user is not running the app, it has to be OS4 only!

Comment: @Amorya:Thanks for sharing your thoughts.I am going to try the same.